# Port monitoring software or category of solution

Tags: monitoring, sysadmin

I need help finding a piece of software, or at least a *type* of software.

I have an application server that runs MANY programs on MANY ports, my use case involves multiple DB servers, email, multiple web servers etc - but a bigger problem is that a solution I came up with for one aspect of the application involves dynamically creating, using, and then deleting vhosts for Apache on a specific port range.

I need a way to actively monitor ALL my ports, to see the software that is using the port, and the traffic currently going over it (a bit like netdata if possible, but broken down by ports).

I have been looking for almost 2 days for this, the best option I have found is Nmap, but it only runs scans, so I would have to schedule scans, aggregate the data, and produce my own views since every front end I can find for it (browser based) is buggy as all hell. More surprisingly, it seems CRAZY to me that there isn't  simple piece of software that can just show me a current readout of my ports and what they're doing to troubleshoot my application stack! I can't be the only one with this need...

To give an example; logio.org is an active log viewing software, it lets me monitor and view log updates in real time. This lets me run portions of my application, then see the access and error logs as they happen. I could really use something like that for ports - but I absolutely can't find it

So I have come to ask the server peeps - how can I accomplish this? Is their a software that does this or will I have to write this most painfully obvious tool myself?

Comment: This is not a request for a recommendation - it is a request for a specific solution. I am NOT asking what is better, what do you like - etc. I have outlined VERY specific criteria and there is a correct answer or there isn't (the question is carefully crafted). The steps taken are explained - the research outlined - ALL aspects of the S.E. terms on the matter are satisfied. I have answered well outlined requests like this on Stack Overflow before as they ARE appropriate for that, and this, Stack Exchange. Please correct this error or I'm not helping you with your software anymore ;p

Comment: This is a request for an opinion: “Enterprise Monitoring Solution” with the lightest agent?" If I say Nagios is the lightest, that's an opinion. If I say "yes, it can monitor all ports actively" - that is not an opinion, it is a fact

Comment: Yet this is not booted for opinion?? I take the time to make sure I ask the question effectively and stay within the terms and get flagged but this gets answers and upvotes?? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197169/can-beehive-detect-a-snowden-like-actor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#readme). It may not do everything you ask for, in particular it does not log anything, it only aggregates data and it shows the results realtime, but if you leave it running in a [screen session](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and configure `screen` to log the output to a file, I think the solution could fill nearly all the gaps.

There's also [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) that specifically aggregates data by IP port, but I've never used it, so I'm not sure about what it can do. It surely can run in a screen session though.

[Darkstat](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) is yet another tool I haven't tried myself, but that seems to suit your needs.

Comment: Yeah - nethogs is what I was looking at prior, I guess it really is the only option here - I wish I didn't have to force my other dev's to SSH in just to make sure the server they expect to be running on port (n) is up and running...